# Unlinking two modules in the designer - how do I remove the arrow?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a ludicrously simple question but one that I cannot decipher, unfortunately, for myself. I am doing the DP-100 certification and am working through the tutorials and I have insert an "Execute python script" module in between the "Score Model" and "Web service output" modules.

I cannot do this. On the left is what I currently have and on the right is what I'm trying to achieve.

Excruciatingly, it does not let me link the "Execute python script" to the "Web service output" module as it is still linked to the "Score model" module. How can I unlink these two? There is surely an extremely simple way, but nothing intuitive works. Double clicking, right clicking, dragging / dropping, nothing.

[What I have and what the tutorial is telling me to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtkey.png)

I know I can delete the final "Web service output" module and create another but *surely* that is not the best way to do this. If I had a module with a lot of specific params set up, I'd have to create it again from scratch!

Any help is massively appreciated.

[Where I get to when I try to add the python script module and then re-draw the connective arrows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNr4T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out a day later: you click on the arrow linking the two modules, *then* you right-click on the node it's pointing to and hit "delete". Not the most intuitive but this is how it works.